# Hiding/replacing code in VBA

Tags: vba, hide

I have a large chunk of code that manually defines each element of an array for me that is annoyingly long and positioned at the beginning of one of my functions.  I would like to hide the code or set it somewhere else WITHOUT changing its current meaning in any way if possible.  I would like to avoid making the array global.  It's also not reasonable to pass the array from all the places that the function is called.

Is there some way to simply have the code sit somewhere else while VBA sees it as being a part of the function, i.e. as if I had all the elements defined at the beginning of the function?  I imagine having some sort of "Sub" that's not actually a Sub (I might call it an "Excerpt") of code with the elements populated there with a single line in the function that calls the "Excerpt" by name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return an array from a function so it could be in a module on its own;

```
public Function getArr() as string()
    Dim arr(10) as string
    ...
    arr(5) = "Cakey"
    getArr = arr
End Function
```

Called with

```
Dim arry() as string: arry = getArr()
msgbox arry(5)
```